# filling a canvas shape with text

Tags: html, canvas, drawing

i am trying to figure out how to add a text to a canvas shape
for example here is my **Code**:

```
var text ="5"; // text to display over the circle
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(50,70, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

i would very much appriciate it if someone would help me adding the text to the shape
thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
i figure out that i need to write again on the canvas so this is what i got so far ... but 
the text doesnt allign to the center of the circle :

```
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.beginPath();
  var radius = 10; // for example
  context.arc(200, 200, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with
  var font = "bold " + radius +"px serif";
  context.font = font;
  context.textBaseline = "top";
  context.fillText(text, 200-radius/4 ,200-radius/2);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DKcpS/

The text is getting drawn *starting* in the center of the circle, and starting with the top of the text since you put the `textBaseline` to `top`.

This is the same text centered roughly using the width and height of the text:

http://jsfiddle.net/DKcpS/1/

As you can see we have a `context.measureText(theTextToMeasure)` function that returns a `textMetrics` object that has a width property. For now it does not have a height one, so we have to sort of guess that.