# Bingo ball on Canvas using Math.random

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to draw a bingo ball on canvas that displays a random number using Math.random, how do i pass the function into it?

```
function drawCircle(ctx,x,y,r,colour,rn) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.5;
    ctx.fillStyle= colour;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle =  'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)';
    ctx.font = 'italic 40pt Calibri ';
    ctx.fillText(rn, x-10, y+5);
}
```

Comment: `rn = Math.floor((Math.random() * 90) + 1);` before the `ctx.fillText()` should do the job. or you could do this in the parameters when calling the function.

Comment: var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

Comment: sorry could you please tell me how i would pass it into the above code? thank you

Comment: call your drawCircle function like this: `drawCircle(ctx, 100, 75, 50, <your color>, Math.floor((Math.random() * 90) + 1));`

Comment: thank you for your help kevin. I am struggling with the layout what would be the best way to draw a ball with a random number in the centre? thanks again

Comment: [this is what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260176/filling-a-canvas-shape-with-text)

Comment: Cheers Kevin appreciate the helps.

Comment: glad i could help :)