# How to add text along with color in custom shapes made through canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have been writing some javascript to  create custom shapes as you can see in the below code snippet. I was successfully able to fill the shapes with different colors but when I try to use the fillText property of canvas, the background color disappears and only the text is there in the applied fillStyle. I want to keep both the text and background color intact. How can this be achieved?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('newCanvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(280,300);
      ctx.lineTo(240,300);
      ctx.lineTo(280,200);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
      ctx.fillText('1',270,250);
      //ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(280,300);
      ctx.lineTo(280,250);
      ctx.lineTo(240,300);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle='#EAF356';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(280,300);
      ctx.lineTo(320,300);
      ctx.lineTo(280,200);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle='green';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(280,300);
      ctx.lineTo(280,250);
      ctx.lineTo(320,300);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle='#F59A4E';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="newCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260176/filling-a-canvas-shape-with-text

Comment: Thank you so much Cat. That actually helped.

Comment: Awesome. It was actually just the 2nd google result for "add text to shapes on canvas", so no sweat.